# How to dynamicly load of controller and action (Zend Framework + AJAX)?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-controller

I am trying to write a universal code for AJAX. I will show what I mean on the example of the e-shops admin panel. There are some things that we can edit, for example: categories, products, attributes. Each of those elements have its forms with input text and input checkbox fields etc. Saving is going to look like in Gmail, when you write something in the field it is automaticaly sent request to server. For each module (categories, products, attributes...) I have a controller and an action in it for example for edition editAction, for deleting deleteAction etc. It sometimes that I have in one view more than one form concerning controllers. In main layout I have a JS code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/fa.fronted/public/en/controller/action/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'websiteid='+iWebId+'&formid='+iFormId+'&formfieldid='+iFieldId+'&'+dataName+'='+dataValue,
      success: function(data) {
          if(data=='OK') {
              $('#ajaxmessage').text('All changes saved');
          }
          else{
              $('#ajaxmessage').text('Error: ' + data);
          }
      },
      error: function() {
          $('#ajaxmessage').text('Error');
      }
  });
}
```

I would like to use different URL addresses for different controllers and actions - I want to do this dynamicaly or manage it in the form.

Comment: Please end your post with a real question or two. What is your problem, what did you try, what didn't work?

Comment: You want one Ajax function to post to all controllers and the url should be same for all post...... right ??

Comment: If I guessed right, you can obtain the controller and action name through the request, make a parent controller, that all controllers extend and in the preDispatch() you can set view vars from $this->_request->getControllerName(), and getActionName, then make a call of this js with the controller and action as args

Comment: @Omar A. Shaaban Yes I know I can use this method to get the name of controller and action but how to use this if I send request from one controller to another. For example I'm in IndexControler and indexAction and I want to sand request to fooController and action barAction. The JS code is in layout used to all controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onChangeCallback(controller,action,formId){
    var data = getFormData(formId); 
    // or if you want to save by field $(this).val() will get you the input value
    // make the ajax request from the code posted in your question
}

<input type="text" name="username" onchange="return onChangeCallback('<?=$this->ControllerName?>'
,'<?=$this->actionName?>','myForm')" />
```